# tod_training features.config.yaml options

Tags: ros, tod-training, tod-detecting

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki page doesn't list the options for this yaml file. Where are these listed and read in? I'm having very mixed results.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9573/tod_training-features.config.yaml-options/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TOD is currently unsupported and is seeing a big overhaul. Once the API is stable we will release it again (we plan around July/August 2011).
I updated the wiki for the parameters we use internally so please trust that. Other features/descriptors are possible. For example, for SIFT you would use:
detector_type: SIFT
extractor_type: sequential
descriptor_type: SIFT
detector_params:
max_features: 2000.
min_features: 1000.
extractor_params:
octaves: 3.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2